# MySQL LEFT JOIN ON JSON to get values

Tags: mysql, json

```
Streams:

+----+-----------+
| id |   server  |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | ["1","15"]|
+----+-----------+

Servers:

+----+-------------------+------------------+
| id | server            |      download    |
+----+-------------------+------------------+
|  1 | Server #1         |      2.05        |
|  2 | Server #2         |      23.96       |
|  3 | Server #3         |      8.08        |
| 15 | Server #15        |      3.03        |
+----+-------------------+------------------+
```

I need to get thus for result:

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id |   server  |  download    |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | Server #1 |     2.05     |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

So basically i need to get from streams table server field and that field need to read from servers table what server have lower download and return that server like reult table posted above.

```
SELECT servers.server FROM servers
LEFT JOIN streams ON servers.id=CAST(json_extract(streams.server, '$[0]') AS 
UNSIGNED)
WHERE streams.id=1;
```

So i get only first server from result not two...so that i can then compare what have lover download...i know that problem is '$[0]' but i don't know how to left join or how to read all values from streams server (1 and 15) and then to add witch is lover from that two...what i im missing?

Comment: Deleted mine question because off the many comments. 
 
i advice you to create a connection table named `stream_server` with columns `id`, `stream_id` and `server_id`.. This is called normalization this way you can write a better optimal JOIN statement. good luck

Comment: I know that i need to define data other way you described..but i have connected this rows and table structure to whole my system (add edit delete activate deactivate...) so i need to get this in one query or two queries...

Comment: for every valid item in the JSON this could be one item or two items or ten items you need a seperate LEFT JOIN there isn't a better solution

Comment: ok thanks..that i need to know...so i need to run two queries..one query that reads server id from streams and other to contains for server id in servers table..thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should also extract the second JSON value and `LEFT JOIN` it again like this.

```
SELECT servers.server FROM servers

LEFT JOIN streams ON servers.id = CAST(json_extract(streams.server, '$[0]') AS 
UNSIGNED)    
LEFT JOIN streams ON servers.id = CAST(json_extract(streams.server, '$[1]') AS 
UNSIGNED)

WHERE streams.id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks..but i im getting this error when runing your query: ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'streams' And also sometimes it there two numbers in json sometimes is one..and sometimes is 10 values in json so this $[0] and $[1] is not good

Comment: @John "And also sometimes it there two numbers in json sometimes is one..and sometimes is 10 values"  Then i advice you to create a connection table named stream_server with columns id, stream_id and server_id.. This is called normalization

Comment: Ok..but is there a way that i can run this in one query? to LEFT JOIN streams.server json ON servers.id? This way if is possible it can be done in one query.....above way i need to run 2 times query and when server is under large load this will be not good